# GCC include path on Windows for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, windows, gcc

I am trying to compile Objective-C program on Windows. Installed all 3 packages from [here](http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html)
Now the problem is, when I try to compile a simple Hello World program, It is unable to find the header files. (Foundation/Foundation.h)

I searched SO before posting, and tried these methods

- (**Absolute Path**) Able to find *Foundation.h* file, but that file (Foundation.h) is dependent on some other file (*GNUstepBase/GSVersionMacros.h*) which the compiler is not able to find.
- **With -I Option**, the compiler is not able to find any file (including Foundation.h)
- I also tried adding to windows **PATH**. It didn't help either.

Can you point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://sweettutos.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/objective-c-on-windows-yes-you-can/ It uses the same packages you need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add `framework` directory with `-F` to compiler.

On Mac it would be I believe `-F/System/Library/Frameworks/` where in that directory is `Foundation.framework`

Comment: No folder that I can Locate in GNUStep Installation. The above header files are in Library folder.